# non listable plus and times

Tags: evaluation, attributes

I am trying to create my own `Plus` and `Times` functions, which are identical to the built in ones with the exception that they are only `Listable` for numerical arguments, or for `List` arguments (which in my context will always be numerical lists).

My attempt so far is this:

```
ClearAll[CircleTimes, CirclePlus]
Attributes[CirclePlus] = Attributes[CircleTimes] = 
                         Complement[Attributes[Plus], {Listable, Protected}];
CircleTimes[a_, b_, c___] := CircleTimes[a*b, c] 
                          /;numericOrList[a] && numericOrList[b];
CirclePlus[a_, b_, c___] := CirclePlus[a+b, c] 
                          /;numericOrList[a] && numericOrList[b];
CirclePlus[CircleTimes[a_, x1_], CircleTimes[a_, x2_]] := CircleTimes[a, x1 + x2] 
                          /; numericOrList[x1] && numericOrList[x2];
numericOrList[a_] := NumericQ[a] || Head[a] === List;
```

This is only a partial solution though, because these do not yet have the property `CirclePlus[a]=a`. This leads to for example:

```
expr = Sin[z] f[z] + z^3 f[z] + 3 (z^2 + 1);
rule = {Plus->CirclePlus,Times->CircleTimes};
expr/.rule/.{f_[z]:>f[z],z->{1.,2.,3.}}
```

which outputs

```
3 (c*) CirclePlus[{2., 5., 10.}] (c+) f[z] (c*) {1.84147, 8.9093, 27.1411}
```

(I wrote `(c*)` and `(c+)` for `CircleTimes` and `CirclePlus` here, which have their own symbol in Mathematica)

So we get `3 (c*) CirclePlus[{2., 5., 10.}]` where we want to get just `{6.,15.,30.}`.

I would think that I just need to add to the definition:

```
CircleTimes[a_] := a
CirclePlus[a_] := a
```

But this causes an infinite recursion that I don't understand and don't know how to fix.

How can I include this?

The point of these functions is to evaluate all the numerical parts in an expression, keeping the symbolic parts as is (i.e. not turning `a*{1.,2.,3.}` into `{1. a, 2. a, 3. a}`, because `a` might be a vector).
Apart from this issue this was the most elegant way I found of doing that.

Comment: @CarlWoll Thanks, this solved the recursion here but it didn't solve my larger problem. I've just posted a more general question about that.